# How can I run LaunchedEffect for a specified times?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

This question is related with my app's some part. The scenario of this question is after I click START button I want circle scale up and down for 3 time with specified times like scale up for 4 seconds etc. I have almost done this code but I can not figure out how to run this for 3 times after I click the button. (I want circle up and down for 3 times after every click to button) Can you help me? Code is below :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ProgressBarTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    BallScaleIndicator()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun BallScaleIndicator() {
    var isScalingUp by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val animationProgressForText by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (isScalingUp) 1f else 0.0f,
        animationSpec = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 12000
            0.0f at 0
            0.8f at 4000
            0.8f at 6000
            1f at 12000
        },
        label = ""
    )

    val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (isScalingUp) 0.8f else 0.6f,
        animationSpec = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 12000
            0.6f at 0
            0.8f at 4000
            0.8f at 6000
            0.6f at 12000
        },
        label = ""
    )

    Column {

        Button(onClick = {
            isScalingUp = true
        }) {
            Text(text = "START")
        }

        Ball(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(500.dp)
                .padding(16.dp)
                .scale(animationProgress),
            animationProgress = animationProgressForText,
            isScalingUp = isScalingUp
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isScalingUp) {
        delay(12000) // Wait for one complete animation cycle
    }
    isScalingUp = false

}

@Composable
fun Ball(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    borderColor: Color = Color.Black,
    borderWidth: Dp = 40.dp,
    animationProgress : Float,
    isScalingUp : Boolean
) {
    var text: String = "START"

    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Canvas(
            modifier = modifier,
            onDraw = {
                val canvasSize = size.minDimension
                val circleRadius = (canvasSize - borderWidth.toPx()) / 2
                val circleCenter = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)

                // Draw the empty circle (just the border)
                drawCircle(
                    color = borderColor,
                    center = circleCenter,
                    radius = circleRadius,
                    style = Stroke(width = borderWidth.toPx())
                )


            }
        )

        Text(
            text = if (animationProgress > 0.0 && animationProgress < 0.79999995) "TAKE BREATH"
            else if (animationProgress in 0.79999995..0.8000001) "HOLD ON"
            else if (animationProgress == 0.0f) "START"
            else "GIVE BREATH",
            fontSize = 35.sp,
            color = Color.Black)
    }

}
```

Comment: My first guess would be to use something other than `animateFloatAsState`, which gives you more control over the `animationProgress`. But I'm not aware of any function in the library that does that. Perhaps you can look at the implementation of `animateFloatAsState` and build it yourself?

Comment: Actually if there is an alternative to this approach it would be good for me also.